# How to install anaconda in Eos? Explain please

Tags: software-installation

How to install anaconda in elementary Os please explain step by step process

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Page:  [Download Site](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux)
2. [Installer Instructiions](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux)